# SQLITE3: Union of two unrelated tables with multilines

Tags: sqlite, union, group-concat, coalesce

I have simplified this problem so it's easier to post.  I am stuck on adding the configurations table which is not related in any way to the other tables.  If you'd rather skip to see what my real problem is, please look at the final output that is current and the final output that is desired.  For convenience, I have a non working SQL solution at the end.

Please help and thanks in advance!

**Background**:

Basically I've got a statement that has 8 inner joins to connect various table data.  I had originally had 8 different queries, but on my embedded machine, the queries run about 2-3 seconds long each making the total time around 20-30 seconds total.  This is way too long.  Most of that time is transaction setup and teardown; the queries were very fast.  Since I'd like the data within a 1-2 second timeframe, I decided to combine all of the queries into a single query.  Unfortunately, the tables themselves are duplicates of an external database that isn't queriable from the embedded device; I am not willing to combine the data at this point into a single table.  The device has only python2.5 and sqlite3, though I have installed sqlalchemy and I'm using the ORM generally in my code.  Unfortunately, I am unable to produce more binaries on the machine, but I can write as much python as my heart desires.

**Data**

table 1: users

```
name   | number | data
 --------------------------------
 alpha   | 12345 | special
 beta     | 54321 | special-er
```

Table 2 (unrelated to table 1):  configuration

```
name   | data
 --------------------------------
 lang  | eng
 big     | 24
 medium | 20
 small | 13
```

Final Table Output what I'm currently getting:

```
name   | number | data          | config
 -----------------------------------------------
 alpha   | 12345 | special       | {null}
 beta     | 54321 | special-er  | {null}
 {null}    | {null}   | {null}           | lang:eng
 {null}    | {null}   | {null}           | big:24
 {null}    | {null}   | {null}           | medium:20
 {null}    | {null}   | {null}           | small:13
```

Final Table Output what I want:

```
name   | number | data          | config
 -----------------------------------------------
 alpha   | 12345 | special       | lang:eng, big:24, medium:20, small:13
 beta     | 54321 | special-er  | lang:eng, big:24, medium:20, small:13
```

**Current (non working) Solution**

This is what I have so far:

```
<!-- language: sql -->
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT u.name as name
                 ,u.number as number
                ,u.data as data
                ,NULL as config
FROM users u
UNION
 SELECT NULL as name
                 ,NULL as number
                 ,NULL as data
                 ,c.name||":"||c.data as config
 FROM configurations c
 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just issue the selects as two separate statements in the same transaction?

I am doing something similar, where I am sending SQL over an HTTP link and sending the data back formatted as JSON.  The latency of the link is 1-2 seconds, so sending multiple requests is right out.  In my case, I found that I could just issue the select calls separated by a semi-colon, e.g. something like this might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT u.name as name
                 ,u.number as number
                ,u.data as data
                ,NULL as config
FROM users u; 

SELECT NULL as name
                ,NULL as number
                ,NULL as data
                ,c.name||":"||c.data as config
FROM configurations c
) t
```

Note: I just copied what you had an replaced the UNION with a semi-colon, on second look that might not be quite right, but hopefully you get the idea.

I'm not sure if you need to wrap this in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` ... `END TRANSACTION` - I do this automatically on the server for all queries.  I am also using the C interface to SQLITE3, getting a callback to a function for each row in which I generate the JSON table for the reply. I am not distinguishing between the results of each query; they all go to the same function, so this might be the magic that makes this work in my case - it produces funny results if each query doesn't have the same number of columns.

Comment: I'm working on an embedded device using an ARM processor that's several generations old (read: really slow).  Two selects just takes too long for my application.